# ResourcesCompat constructor has private acess

Tags: android, constructor, android-support-library

error is very clear but the google android docs says the constructor is public.

I've used below code in my app

```
import android.support.v4.content.res.ResourcesCompat;

final ResourcesCompat resourcesCompat = new ResourcesCompat();
    final int foreground = resourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), night ? R.color.night_status_bar_text : R.color.status_bar_text, getTheme());
    final int background = resourcesCompat.getColor(getResources(), night ? R.color.night_game_background : R.color.game_background, getTheme());
    statusBar.setTextColor(foreground);
```

I've added android-v4 support library latest one (support-v4 24.0.0). Android studio is giving 'ResourcesCompat constructor has private access' but google docs says that constructor is public.

Please help me to get solve this.

Comment: Could you post a link to the support lib v24. I can't find it in any branch https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+refs

Comment: I've downloaded 'support-v4 24.0.0 ' from SDK manager and added as library using project structure in Android studio

Comment: OK thanks. I currently can't check it, but it could be possible, that they made the `getColorStateList` and the `getColor` static and made the constuctor private.  (and the Documentation will be updated if v24 gets officially released)

Comment: check out my update ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use 23.2.1 which is the latest at the moment. (March 2016)

Check out [this](http://developer.android.com/intl/ru/tools/support-library/index.html) site for more informations.

I've tested it with this version. It works fine and the contructor is in fact public.

**Update:**

OK I found it [ResouresCompat v24](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/support.git/+/android-n-preview-1/v4/java/android/support/v4/content/res/ResourcesCompat.java)

As I expected `getColor` and `getColorStateList` are static now. So there is no need to use a constructor.

Update your code to:

```
final int foreground = ResouresCompat.getColor(getResources(), night ? R.color.night_status_bar_text : R.color.status_bar_text, getTheme());
final int background = ResouresCompat.getColor(getResources(), night ? R.color.night_game_background : R.color.game_background, getTheme());
```

But keep in mind that this is just the preview.

Comment: Thanks for your immediately help. My compilerSDKversion is android-N. Is it create any problems if I use support-v4 23.3.1 in build.grable file ?

Comment: There shouldn't be any problems. The support v24 lib is an alpha/beta version I guess? I'm sure they are working on it, but currently I would recommend to use the latest stable support lib version.

Comment: Thanks for your valuable help. Will change to support-v4 23.2.1